# Plot several boxplots in one figure

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, matplotlib, boxplot

I am using python-3.x and I would like to plot several boxplots in one figure, all the data from one numpy array where the shape of this array is (100, 301)

If I use the code below it will plot them all (I will have 301 boxplots in one figure which is too much)

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.boxplot(my_data)
plt.show()
```

I don't want to plot all the data, I just want to plot 10, 15 or 20 (variable number) of the data by using for loop or any method that work best.

for example, I want to plot boxplots every 50 number of data that mean I will have around 6 boxplots from 301 in my figure, I tried to use for loop but no luck

Any advice would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use indexing to plot every 50th data points using a variable `step`. To have separate box plots and avoid overlapping, you can specify the positions of individual box plot using the `positions` parameter. `my_data[:, ::step]` gives you the desired data to plot. Below is an example using some random data.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

my_data = np.random.randint(0, 20, (100, 301))
step = 50

posit = range(my_data[:, ::step].shape[1])
ax.boxplot(my_data[:, ::step], positions=posit)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for the help, but the problem in your way will plot all the boxplots over each other

Comment: @azeez: Check my edit. You can specify the positions of individual box plot using the `positions` parameter

Comment: Thank you very much, that answer my question

Comment: @Sheldore I have the same problem(ish) but I am trying to plot for each sub-folder in a directory, first I have problem with collecting all plots together and second I can not  label them as my sub-folders name. [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62301864/how-to-unseparate-plots-in-boxplot?noredirect=1#comment110187149_62301864)