# how to unseparate plots in boxplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have plotted a box plot through a directory that has 6 subfolders within. When I write `plt.boxplot(my_list)` with writing `plt.show()` it plots 6 different graphs and without writing that, all 6 plots will overlay on each other. How can I unseparate them and make them collected in one graph? Also, is it possible to use `label=directory` for using in X-Axis?
The code that I have written is below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
sns.set(style="darkgrid")
root = r'/home/hossein/Desktop/Out/INTERSECTION/BETA 15'
xx=[]
percentage=[]
gg=[]
my_list = os.listdir(root)
my_list =  [file for file in my_list if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(root, file))]
for directory in my_list:
    CASES = [file for file in os.listdir(os.path.join(root, directory)) if file.startswith('config')]   
    if len(CASES)==0:
        continue
    CASES.sort()   
    percentage=[]  
    for filename in CASES:      
        with open(os.path.join(root, directory,filename), "r") as file: 
            lines = file.readlines()
            x = [float(line.split()[0]) for line in lines]
            y = [float(line.split()[1]) for line in lines]
            g = np.linspace(min(y),max(y),100)
            h = min(y)*0.9
            t = max(y)*0.9
            xx=[]
            gg= []
            for i in range(1,len(x)):
                if (y[i] < h or y[i] > t):
                    xx.append(x[i])
            percent = len(xx)/len(y)
            percentage.append(percent)
    plt.boxplot(percentage,)

#     plt.show()
```

could you please provide me with examples

[image]

Comment: Try passing x-values as positions using `plt.boxplot(percentage, positions=range(len(percentage)))`

Comment: @Sheldore with this I got `List of boxplot statistics and "positions" values must have same the length`

Comment: @RishaanGupta it was not my answer. I have used a `for loop` which is not able to do for every cycle. Also, I have used `plt.show()` once a time and it did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is passing a list to `positions`. Also, `plt.show()` must be called outside the loop.

Here is a quick example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
b = [5,6,7,8,9]

data = [a,b]

for i, x in enumerate(data):
    plt.boxplot(x, positions=[i])
plt.show()
```

[image]

You can always change the ticks labels with anything you want.

In this case, you I change `[0,1]` to `['dir_A','dir_B']`:

```
plt.xticks([0,1], ['dir_A','dir_B'])
plot.show()
```

[image]

Comment: How can I make my different lists to a list? Is it right to write `data=[percentage[i]]`

Comment: @Mir.Emad try:  `for _i, directory in enumerate(my_list)` ... `plt.boxplot(percentage, positions=[_i])` You will get a plot per directory.

Comment: Is it possible to read labels from my directory names? I mean not manually, automatically by reading the name of subfolders

Comment: sure: `plt.xticks(list(range(len(my_list))), my_list)` This will map the directory you have in my_list with the ticks on the plot.

Comment: In your case, however, `if len(CASES)==0: continue` would complicate things a little. But you can append `_i` and `directory` in separate lists during the loop and then use that for the mapping of the ticks. Unfortunately, I can't help much more that this since I don't have your inputs and I can't test all the possibility. I think the code I wrote is quite easy to understand, now it's up to you to experiment a bit with it.